# Can I locally place a directory at a different location with Subversion?

Tags: svn

My project in rep:
project/dir A/
project/dir B/

(MacOSX) Locally:
project/dir A/
~/somewhere/dir B/

Workflow:
Don´t forget to copy "~/somewhere/dir B/" to "project/dir B/" before commit...

Alias? Script? Flag? Easiest solution wins as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want. You could check out `dir A` and `dir B` into different locations and work with them separately. If you want to work with 'project' directory and check consistency at the commit, you might check out [svn hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

Comment: Hooks don't seem to help me in this case but a nice find

Answer (score 1):

You can check out `~/somewhere/dir B/` as an independent working copy. No need to copy it anywhere, just remember check it in.